# VS Cloud Load Test - Could not locate directory/file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, load-testing, msloadtest

I'm trying to load test our application at work and I have created a web-test (coded web-test) that works perfectly locally.

It uses a helper class to create data that's required for the application like name, email etc (which must be unique for each application).

Name is returned by a method that resides in helper class as an object of Name class which is pretty basic contains 2 props First and Last.

```
public static Name GetRandomName()
{
    // if (!File.Exists(@"..\..\..\Apps-Load-Performance-Tests\Data Files\fNames_1.csv")) return new Name();

    var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\..\Apps-Load-Performance-Tests\Data Files\fNames_1.csv");
    var maxLength = allLines.Length;
    var random = new Random();
    return new Name
    {
        First = allLines[random.Next(maxLength)],
        Last = allLines[random.Next(maxLength)]
    };
}
```

Problem is when I run a load test via Visual Studio cloud - it throws FileNotFoundException (fNames_1.csv)

In my test settings - I have 'Enable Deployment' checked and added the .csv file and the directory that contains the .csv file... but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I also tried adding [DeploymentItem()] attribute but no go...

What am I doing wrong? Any help or if someone can point me to right direction - I'd highly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment via the options listed in the question copies files into the `TestResults\{{name+datetime+etc}}\Out` directory for the test run. The relative path in the question appears to be expecting the `Apps-Load-Performance-Tests` directory to be in the same directory as `TestResults`, or even closer to the root directory.

For a cloud load test the files need to be deployed to the cloud computer that runs the test and into the same directories as the other parts of the deployed test. I suggest changing the directory paths in the `GetRandomName` method and related code to expect the files to be in the `TestResults\...\Out` directory for the run. Also make sure the files are deployed to there.

Comment: thanks! Thats what it was - when test is run on the cloud it wasn't able to find the file at that path defined. So what I ended up doing was @"/filename.csv" for local execution and @"filename.csv" for cloud (notice the slash - without slash it won't work on local execution -- weird)

Thanks again for your help and your time! Cheers

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Where exactly should I keep the file in my project so that while running the tests the file can be found?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Put it in one of the directories in your solution and make sure that the file is deployed.